# Rename a file from node1.html to node001.html

Tags: bash, shell

I have to rename the former 99 files: node1.html, node2.html ... to node001.html, node002.html ...

```
i=1
for file in $(ls | grep [1-99].html$)
do
                mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's/$file/${file}00${i}/g')
               i=$(( $i+1 ))   
done
```

But unfornately reports me an error:

> move: node1.html and node1.html are the same file
>
> move: node2.html and node2.html are the same file
>
> ...

- What's the problem?

Comment: If you want to use variables inside sed you must use double quotes.

Comment: Do you want to re-sequence the file - if file15.html is missing do you want file16.html to be file016.html or file015.html ?

Comment: Unexpected result: it renames as node1.html001 and not node001.html

Comment: I want to rename nodeN.html to node00N.html :-)

Comment: But what about node12.html ? Answer refer to '99' files

Comment: `grep [1-99].html$` does not mean what you think it means. `[1-99]` is a character class which matches a single non-zero digit. In other words, it means *exactly* the same thing as `[1-9].html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following bash brace expansion also:

```
for i in {1..99}
do 
    if [ -f "node${i}.html" ] ; then 
       echo "mv node${i}.html node$(printf "%03d" ${i}).html"
       mv node${i}.html node$(printf "%03d" ${i}).html
    fi
done
```

**Example** (*excluding the actual renaming command*)

```
mv node1.html node001.html
mv node2.html node002.html
mv node3.html node003.html
mv node4.html node004.html
mv node5.html node005.html
mv node6.html node006.html
...
...
...
mv node95.html node095.html
mv node96.html node096.html
mv node97.html node097.html
mv node98.html node098.html
mv node99.html node099.html
```

Comment: @HeyBoo, thank you. It's glad to know that this post also helped you resolve the problem, taking into account of other solutions provided by respective authors.

Answer (score 0):

Other than quoting, (see comment above), the code will not work for 2 digit numbers (e.g. 15 will become file0015). Also, there is an issue of order, as node2.html will be processed after node1.html, node11.html, ... node19.html

Also, note that pattern '[1-99], would only match 1 digit sequence.

Assuming the goal is to preserve the numbers - just reformat in 3 digit

```
for file in node[0-9].html *[0-9][0-9].html ; do
     f=${file%.html};
     prefix=${file%%[0-9]*}
     suffix=${f:${#prefix}}
     nn=$(printf '%03d' "$suffix") 
     mv "$file" "$prefix$nn.html"
done
```

Comment: You get an error when you find a file like `a1b2.html`.

Comment: Edit your file filter avoiding `node0.html` and `node100.html`.

Answer (score 0):

First test with

```
for f in node[1-9][0-9].html node[1-9].html; do 
   sed 's/.*/"&" "&"/;s/[0-9]*.html.$/00&/' <<< "$f"
done
```

When the file selection and new names match the expectation, you can feed the output to `mv`:

```
for f in node[1-9][0-9].html node[1-9].html; do
   sed 's/.*/"&" "&"/;s/[0-9]*.html.$/00&/' <<< "$f"
done | xargs -n2 mv
```

Answer (score -1):

Use double quotes in the sed command to detect variables. Also you are not parsing correctly the filename. Note the `cut` command I added so your extension does not get messed up. Your script would end up like this.

```sh
i=1
for file in $(ls | grep [1-99].html$); do
  filename=$(echo ${file} | cut -d '.' -f1)
  mv ${file} $(echo "${filename}" | sed "s/${filename}/${filename}00${i}.html/g")
  i=$(($i+1))
done;
```

Comment: new files are node1001.html, node2002.html and so on. I want them to be node001.html, node002.html and so on. Debugging I noticed that filename is node1, node2, node3 ...

Comment: Great! Didn't check for that. I gave you the answer for sed, the question ... An upvote would be awesome.

Comment: I hope you don't have filenames with spaces. `[1-99]` are the numbers 1 to 9 and 9, so it is the same as `[1-9]`. File `node10.html` will be skipped.

Comment: When `node5.html` is missing,  `node6.html` is renamed to `node005.html`.

Comment: Question was about sed, not how to write the script.